# Ninguém ganhou a medalha "Beta"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, medalhas

A descrição da medalha [beta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/30/beta) diz:

> Participou ativamente no beta privado.

O beta privado já acabou, mas ninguém ganhou essa medalha. Foi alguma falha do sistema, ou no nosso caso ela será distribuída ao fim do beta público?

Comment: Mas qual o conceito de participou activamente? Verdade que a minha parede sente falta dessa medalha, mas se calhar ninguém foi activo o suficiente :) **Nota:** +1 pois à muito que andava a pensar nisso!

Comment: Se nem o bigown foi ativo o suficiente, os critérios seriam exigentes demais, não? Acredito que seja mesmo um bug (como nosso site é "diferente", certos scripts automáticos da Area 51 não devem ter rodado aqui).

Comment: Hmmm... o abandono por parte do sistema aos utilizadores activos deveria dar direito a [ganhar esta medalha](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161/223) :)

Comment: Pelo menos deveria ser melhor escrita a descrição desta medalha, os requisitos, por exemplo. Porém acredito que ela não tenha sido levada em conta, como disse o @Zuul.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A criação dessa medalha é manual ao migrar o site do beta privado para o público. E os devs esqueceram (programadores....)

Já tá tudo certo.

Comment: Valeu, Gabe. E eu achando que tudo era automatizado :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Casa de ferreiro...

Comment: Novo filme: "Os 101 originais" :).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Eu quero o Brad Pitt pro meu papel!